# Javafx, Determine a specific timeout for reading from socket

Tags: sockets, javafx, timeout

In code below, in a thread (not UI thread) I'm trying to read data from a socket. But in each state I want to break the while loop if it took more than 3 seconds. How can I do that?

*you can find Some comments in the code*

```
System.out.println(loginMsg);//send login message to server
while ((fromServer = sInput.readLine()) != null) {
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            if (fromServer.equals("*2*1#")) //Login was successful
            {
                sOutput.println(msg); // send another message to server to enter some data into database
                state = 1;
            } else if (fromServer.equals("*2*0#")) //Login was not successful
            {
                motor1CommandString = "access denied";
                state = 3;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (fromServer.equals("*6*1#"))
            {
                motor1CommandString = "message sent";
                state = 2;
            } else if ((fromServer.equals("*6*2#")) /*device is not online */ ||     (fromServer.equals("*6*0#")))  /*for some reason device is not reachable */{
                motor1CommandString = "No Connection to device";
                state = 3;
            }
           break;
        case 2:
            if (fromServer.equals(ACK)) //device has received the message and replied back
                state = 3;
        break;
    }
    if (state == 3) {
        break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Call [`setSoTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) on the socket (before you try to read from it). Then `readLine` will throw a `SocketTimeoutException` if no data is read before the timeout expires. You can catch that exception outside of the loop.

Comment: You mean on every readline() it throws a SocketTimeoutException  if no data is read before the timeout expires?

Comment: Thank you very much. Suppose that we have not this exception in Java. Do you know another way to do the job?